# Reading a session variable to write to the database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, session

If someone could help me out with this I'd really appreciate it - I almost have it working!

Basically, I'm making my own application idea for a while, the reason I'm doing it is because I am new to coding, so I felt it would teach me a lot about the different elements (i.e. adding, updating and deleting records).

So with this example, I have a user logging in successfully and it's creating a session which is being passed along the other forms. I want them to be able to add a deal - which I almost have but seem to struggle with one part.

My HTML code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Find A Deal</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/findadeal/themes/deal.css" />
<style>
    #login-button {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }        
</style>
<script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>    
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom3.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom4.js"></script>

       <?php
    if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ){
     session_start();
        }

    if( isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ){
      /* User is logged in */
      echo "IT WORKS!";
        } ?>

</head>


<body>
<div data-role="page" id="login">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3>Find A Deal</h3>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">

        <label for="username">Enter your username:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="username" id="username"/>
        <label for="password">Enter your password:</label>
        <input type="password" value="" name="password" id="password"/>  
        <a data-role="button" id="login-button" data-theme="b">Login</a>
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

    </div>
</div>

<!--Newly rendered page after successful login!-->

<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h2>Find A Deal</h2>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">

           <?php
    if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ){
     session_start();
        }

    if( isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ){
      echo "IT WORKS!";
        } ?>


    <h3></h3>
    <a href="#view" data-role="button" data-icon="search">View Deals</a>
    <a href="#add" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Add Deals</a>

    </div>
</div>

<!--View Deal Page-->

    <div data-role="page" id="view">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h2>Find A Deal</h2>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">

           <?php
    if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ){
     session_start();
        }

    if( isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ){
      echo "IT WORKS!";
        } ?>


    <h3></h3>
    <p>test so I know I'm onto a new page</p>
    <a href="#view" data-role="button" data-icon="search">View Deals</a>
    <a href="#add" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Add Deals</a>
    </div>

<div data-role="footer">

</div>
</div>

<!--Add Deal Page-->

    <div data-role="page" id="add">
    <script src="js/custom4.js"></script>
    <div data-role="header">
        <h2>Find A Deal</h2>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">

           <?php
    if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ){
     session_start();
        }

    if( isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ){
        echo "It's working!";
        } ?>

    <label for="name">Deal Name:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="name" id="name"/>
        <label for="desc">Description</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="desc" id="desc"/>  
        <a data-role="button" id="submit-button" data-theme="b">Submit</a>
    </div>





</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So just to explain that - the first page is a login page, it brings you next to index which is just a menu page I've set up, then from the menu you can select 1 of 2 pages - view deal and add deal. I'm working with the add deal one at the minute.

When adding a deal the user inputs a deal name and a description into the relevant text boxes so it can be added over to the database. 
I am using this JS function:

```
//Adding a new deal

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#add', function(){ 
 $('#submit-button').on('click', function(){
    if($('#name').val().length > 0 && $('#desc').val().length > 0){
        userObject.name = $('#name').val(); // Put username into the object
        userObject.desc = $('#desc').val(); // Put password into the object
        // Convert an userObject to a JSON string representation
        var outputJSON = JSON.stringify(userObject);
        // Send data to server through ajax call
        // action is functionality we want to call and outputJSON is our data
        ajax.sendRequest({action : 'add', outputJSON : outputJSON});
    } else {
        alert('Please fill all nececery fields');
    }
 });    
});

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
if(userObject.name.length == 0){ // If username is not set (lets say after force page refresh) get us back to the login page
    $.mobile.changePage( "#add", { transition: "slide"} ); // In case result is true change page to Index  
}
$(this).find('[data-role="content"] h3').append('Deal Added:' + userObject.name); // Change header with added message
//$("#index").trigger('pagecreate');
});

// This will be an ajax function set
var ajax = {
sendRequest:function(save_data){
    $.ajax({url: 'http://localhost/findadeal/login/json3.php',
        data: save_data,
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function() {
            // This callback function will trigger before data is sent
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true); // This will show ajax spinner
        },
        complete: function() {
            // This callback function will trigger on data sent/received complete
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); // This will hide ajax spinner
        },
        success: function (result) {
            if(result == "true") {
                $.mobile.changePage( "#index", { transition: "slide"} ); // In case result is true change page to Index
            } else {
                alert('Deal Addition has been unsuccessful, please try again!'); // In case result is false throw an error
            }
            // This callback function will trigger on successful action
        },
        error: function (request,error) {
            // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action                
            alert('Error has occurred, please try again!');
        }
    });
}
}

// We will use this object to store username and password before we serialize it and send to server. This part can be done in numerous ways but I like this approach because it is simple
var userObject = {
name : "",
desc : ""
}
```

This will then be fed over to a PHP file, ready to write the input to the database like this:

```
<?php

$var1 = $_REQUEST['action']; // We dont need action for this tutorial, but in a complex code you need a way to determine ajax action nature
$jsonObject = json_decode($_REQUEST['utputJSON']); // Decode JSON object into readable PHP object

$name = $jsonObject->{'name'}; // Get name from object
$desc = $jsonObject->{'desc'}; // Get desc from object

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  // Conect to mysql, first parameter is location, second is mysql username and a third one is a mysql password
@mysql_select_db("findadeal") or die( "Unable to select database"); // Connect to database called test

$query = "INSERT INTO deal (dname, description) VALUES ('$name' ,'$desc')";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_numrows($result);

if($num != 0) {

    echo "true";

} else {

    echo "false"; 

}
?>
```

This is all working fine, however, the reason the data is not being inserted to the database is because it needs an ID from the user of which the username is being stored in the session variable.

What I would like help with is:

**1.** Can someone show me how you get the data from the session variable and have it brought over to the PHP file.
**2.** Also, the session variable is storing the username - is there a way I can go about checking for its relevant userid tag on its own or will this have to be done through the SQL statement in the PHP file.

I've hope I've not caused any confusion and I've made myself clear about what it is I'm having trouble with. I am a student so all help would be appreciated in the learning process! I'm getting confused in thinking should the session data go though the javascript function like the other data or should it be able to read straight over to the writing PHP file or what? =/

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You can't handle sessions properly in case you already had HTML output. Be sure that you start session (on each page) before you write any line of HTML

Comment: Hi @axel.michel, thanks for the comment back. Have I not handled the session properly? I have a session_start() variable on the PHP the login was reading to then I've the sessions if statement working along  all the other pages being rendered the hold the variable? 
It seemed to have been working for me so far? Should there be something else I should be looking out for?

Comment: why dont you try cookies?

Comment: Cookies? I'll give them a look up so and see what I can find out! 

I hope I'm explaining myself properly, What I'm trying to do is bring the session $_SESSION['username'] over to the PHP file that is writing the other data to the database. Is this someting that would normally help?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand well, you are more interested in learning thing for the moment instead of creating the app. I would suggest you to try learning one thing at a time, in separate test files, and when you have acquired the necessary knowledge then combine all in one application to have everything you learnt applied to a real life test.

I'm working as a coach and have trained many students, and helped them realize some product they can be proud of, so if you are interested in learning things one by one, I think I can help you out, if you like.

Comment: That would be very nice of you, thank you! 

Doing everything piece by piece is how I've structured my learning so far! (it's also so I don't go and break what might take me ages to get working :P )

I just ended up putting everything together after I get a piece working to see the overall flow of the exercise and this is the stage that I'm at. I've done a user registration already and I'm using this as almost the same concept (writing data to a database) but All I'm trying to find out is how I write the usersid to that table also as it's stored in the session variable

Comment: A lot of what I want to do and move onto learning next does reside a lot around the idea of seeing which user is logged in and rendering data specific to their ID etc - that's why learning how to work with the variable in this exercise will help me manipulate it to others at a later stage!

Answer (score 0):

If I got your logic correct, you have to do something like this:

On your login HTML/PHP page start with:

```
<?php
    if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ){ session_start(); }
?>
THE REST OF YOUR CODE FOLLOWS HERE
```

In your Login action PHP Script, again:

```
<?php
    if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ){ session_start(); }
    // now you look up your user - how ever you do this...
    // might be something like this...
    // this is not a real function it should just demonstrate
    // the possible logic.
    if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
        // you just have to check in case no session userid is set:
        function getUser( $username, $password ) {
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
            $sql = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username AND pwd=:pwd';
            $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
            $statement->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->bindParam(':pwd', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->execute();
            $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(!empty($result)) {
                return $result['id'];
            }
            return false;
        }
        // call your login logic (here getUser) and 
        // if you have a result, set the session...
        $userExists = getUser($_POST['user'], $_POST['pwd']);
        if($userExists) {
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $userExists;
        }
    }
?>
```

In the deal action, again:

```
<?php
    if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ){ session_start(); }
    // you check if the username session exists
    if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
        // in case you have...
        // proceed with your deal logic
        // and use $_SESSION['userid'] to fill it to the DB
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hi @axel.michel - thanks for the response. 

There is an element of your answer I think I might be able to use. Can I just ask you however, my user inputs their username and password into the login form and hit login. In the login action PHP script you've given me, does this just take 'THE_USER_ID' filed in the database and save it into the session yes? As in it will read it and save it without the user ever having to input that exact field in the first place?

Comment: @user2025934 I'm not sure if I get your question correctly. I have updated my answer though. What I have posted is not a working script, it is a basic HowTo. Let's say you have a login logic which tests if the user exists and returns the userid on success. This is what you save in the session, then you can use it, you can read this value in all other PHP files (as long as you start the session). No more interaction of the user is required.